# Moving marker on embedded Google Map

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I was wondering if there is a function that I can add to my code to make it possible to move one of my markers (To place it at another position) in a embedded Google Map.

This is my code thus far:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&amp;source=s_d&amp;saddr=Hans+Strijdom+Drive,+Pretoria,+Gauteng,+South+Africa&amp;daddr=Unknown+road&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=FduWdv4dNlewASkhQuYzIl6VHjFEDHPIU_FMeQ%3BFWo1df4dU16xAQ&amp;aq=0&amp;oq=Nkwe&amp;sll=-25.868028,28.409872&amp;sspn=0.046879,0.084543&amp;mra=dme&amp;mrsp=1&amp;sz=14&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=-25.868028,28.409872&amp;spn=0.046879,0.084543&amp;t=m&amp;output=embed&z=12"></iframe>
```

The purpose being, being able to change the "From" marker, but not the "To" marker.

Comment: what do you mean by move ? animation ?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I mean move as in to click on a marker and place it at another position.